# How to Count the number of times a specific key appears across the whole table within an arbitrary key sized json column

Tags: json, postgresql

For example if i have

```
colA
{"a" : 1, "b": 2}
{"b" : 3}
{}
```

I want my result to be:

```
key, count
a, 1
b, 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to deal with nested json structures, you can use `jsonb_object_keys` to iterate over all keys:

```
select x.ky, count(*)
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_object_keys(t.col_a) as x(ky)
group by x.ky
order by x.ky;
```

Comment: Thanks ! great answer